# Hibernate Entity with 2 foreign key options

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have that use case:

I have **table A** and **table B** (none of them is extending the other, they are logically different). Both tables should have a link with one or more **'documents'**.
So I can design table A and table B, but how to design the table for the 'documents'? Should it have 2 foreign key constraints (there is a possibilite one record from documents to have only 1 foreign key to Table A or B and the other foreign key will be null)? How I will declare that in SQL and in Hibernate/JPA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some example code for entity, maybe some sql files. Tnx

Comment: Can one document be linked to both a record of table A and table B? If so, you have to have two foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have one-to-many unidirectional relationship from Table A/B to documents. By doing so, you will require link tables between Table A/B and document (in other words, document will be a master table). Also you will require to store document separately first and then can assign the documents to the Table A/B entities.

Alternatively, if want to save the documents along with Table A/B entity, then you need to maintain both foreign keys which will be nullable i.e. either A or B.

Both approaches are fine hence depending on your business requirement you should pick one.

Comment: yep sounds fine, that is what was in my head but I was searching for approvals and different approaches => thanks a lot.

Comment: I am more for the second option, because TableA<->Documents is already a legacy code. So the case is just to add an other logically different TableB which will have access to the documents too.

Comment: Just it wont be very beautiful with 2 foreign keys in the docs table, but whatever.